# How I can get Daily Sale Detail from QuickBooks Desktop using web connector?

Tags: php, report, quickbooks

I want get all sale data date wise from Quickbooks Desktop. I have following code.

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <?qbxml version="13.0"?>
                <QBXML>
                  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                    <GeneralSummaryReportQueryRq  requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                        <GeneralSummaryReportType>SalesByCustomerSummary</GeneralSummaryReportType>

                          <DisplayReport>false</DisplayReport>
                          <ReportPeriod>
                            <FromReportDate>2011-01-01</FromReportDate>
                            <ToReportDate>2017-09-15</ToReportDate>
                          </ReportPeriod>

                        </GeneralSummaryReportQueryRq>
                      </QBXMLMsgsRq>
                    </QBXML>';

    return $xml;
```

When i replace SalesByCustomerSummary with
DailySalesDetail, then return error, and my second issue how i can stop communication between web connector and quicksbook because it inserts same records for multi time.

Thanks in advance

----------- CODE ------------
I have these two functions:

```
    public function _quickbooks_import_daily_sale_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale){
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <?qbxml version="13.0"?>
                <QBXML>
                  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                    <GeneralDetailReportQueryRq>
                        <GeneralDetailReportType>SalesByItemDetail</GeneralDetailReportType>

                          <DisplayReport>false</DisplayReport>
                          <ReportPeriod>
                            <FromReportDate>2011-01-01</FromReportDate>
                            <ToReportDate>2017-09-15</ToReportDate>
                          </ReportPeriod>

                        </GeneralDetailReportQueryRq>
                      </QBXMLMsgsRq>
                    </QBXML>';

    return $xml;
}

public function _quickbooks_import_daily_sale_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
{   




    $array = array(
                            'text' => $requestID.' <br />'.$xml
                        );
        $this->db->insert('save_response', $array);
//  echo "done";
    return false;
}
```

--------------- FOR QUEUE -----------------------

```
        //echo (__FILE__); exit;
        $user = $this->config->item('quickbooks_user');
        $pass = $this->config->item('quickbooks_pass');

        // Memory limit
        ini_set('memory_limit', $this->config->item('quickbooks_memorylimit'));

        // We need to make sure the correct timezone is set, or some PHP installations will complain
        if (function_exists('date_default_timezone_set'))
        {
            // * MAKE SURE YOU SET THIS TO THE CORRECT TIMEZONE! *
            // List of valid timezones is here: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
            date_default_timezone_set($this->config->item('quickbooks_tz'));
        }

        // Map QuickBooks actions to handler functions
        $map = array(
            //QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_CUSTOMER => array( array( $this, '_quickbooks_customer_import_request' ), array( $this, '_quickbooks_customer_import_response' ) ),
            /*QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_EMPLOYEE => array( array( $this, '_quickbooks_employee_import_request' ), array( $this, '_quickbooks_employee_import_response' ) ),*/
QUICKBOOKS_QUERY_INVOICE => array( array( $this, '_quickbooks_import_daily_sale_request' ), array( $this, '_quickbooks_import_daily_sale_response' ) ),
            //QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_CUSTOMER => array( '_quickbooks_customer_import_request', '_quickbooks_customer_import_response' ), 
            );

        // Catch all errors that QuickBooks throws with this function 
        $errmap = array(
            '*' => array( $this, '_catchallErrors' ),
            );

        // Call this method whenever the Web Connector connects
        $hooks = array(
            QuickBooks_WebConnector_Handlers::HOOK_LOGINSUCCESS => array( array( $this, '_loginSuccess' ) ),    // Run this function whenever a successful login occurs
            );

        // An array of callback options
        $callback_options = array();

        // Logging level
        $log_level = $this->config->item('quickbooks_loglevel');

        // What SOAP server you're using 
        //$soapserver = QUICKBOOKS_SOAPSERVER_PHP;          // The PHP SOAP extension, see: www.php.net/soap
        $soapserver = QUICKBOOKS_SOAPSERVER_BUILTIN;        // A pure-PHP SOAP server (no PHP ext/soap extension required, also makes debugging easier)

        $soap_options = array(      // See http://www.php.net/soap
            );

        $handler_options = array(
            'deny_concurrent_logins' => false, 
            'deny_reallyfast_logins' => false, 
            );      // See the comments in the QuickBooks/Server/Handlers.php file

        $driver_options = array(        // See the comments in the QuickBooks/Driver/<YOUR DRIVER HERE>.php file ( i.e. 'Mysql.php', etc. )
            'max_log_history' => 32000, // Limit the number of quickbooks_log entries to 1024
            'max_queue_history' => 1024,    // Limit the number of *successfully processed* quickbooks_queue entries to 64
            );

        // Build the database connection string
        $dsn = 'mysqli://' . $this->db->username . ':' . $this->db->password . '@' . $this->db->hostname . '/' . $this->db->database;

        // Check to make sure our database is set up 
        if (!QuickBooks_Utilities::initialized($dsn))
        {
            // Initialize creates the neccessary database schema for queueing up requests and logging
            QuickBooks_Utilities::initialize($dsn);

            // This creates a username and password which is used by the Web Connector to authenticate
            QuickBooks_Utilities::createUser($dsn, $user, $pass);
        }

        // Set up our queue singleton
        QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue_Singleton::initialize($dsn);

        // Create a new server and tell it to handle the requests
        // __construct($dsn_or_conn, $map, $errmap = array(), $hooks = array(), $log_level = QUICKBOOKS_LOG_NORMAL, $soap = QUICKBOOKS_SOAPSERVER_PHP, $wsdl = QUICKBOOKS_WSDL, $soap_options = array(), $handler_options = array(), $driver_options = array(), $callback_options = array()

        $Server = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server($dsn, $map, $errmap, $hooks, $log_level, $soapserver, QUICKBOOKS_WSDL, $soap_options, $handler_options, $driver_options, $callback_options);
        $response = $Server->handle();
        $Queue = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($dsn);
            $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_QUERY_INVOICE);


    //exit;
        //echo "<pre>"; print_r($response);
        //echo "Mujtaba";
```

Comment: Post YOUR CODE. Post THE ERROR MESSAGE.

Comment: I have no php error, quickbook returns me xml error like it is not formatted and second is when data communication start then it not stop and i have many multiple rows.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to help until you post your code, and post the error message. It doesn't matter if it's not formatted prettily - it's still helpful to help troubleshoot.

Comment: Hi keith, I have posted code i have. Can you check it

Comment: OK, now please post THE REST of your code. Specifically, the parts related to where/how you're queuing this request up, since you mention that's part of your problem.

Comment: Hi Kieth, the code is there. when i run this code, it is not error, but no response and qb and web connector both hang up at 30%.

Comment: Post a screenshot. Post the Web Connector logs.

Comment: Hi keith, I have solved my issue regarding fetching the item data on daily basis. Can you tell me about i can stop sending concurrent requests from web connector after response. It creates multiple rows for same data. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
    $Queue = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($dsn);
    $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_QUERY_INVOICE);
```

The way the Web Connector works, for every single time the Web Connector connects to QuickBooks, it makes *at least* 2 HTTP requests. So, this script you have is going to run *at least* TWICE every single time things attempt to sync with QuickBooks.

That means that every single time you attempt to sync with QuickBooks, you're queuing up *at least* two requests to do the same thing.

The Web Connector does this:

1. HTTP request #1 - authenticate
2. (if there's stuff to do) HTTP request #2 - ask for the first thing to do
3. (if we got a response back from previous step) HTTP request #3 - send response from QuickBooks back to you
4. (if there's still more stuff to do) go back to step 2.
5. HTTP request #N - close the connection/log off

So, you need to change your code so that you *only queue things up when it first connects* vs. queueing things up on every single HTTP request.

There's an example of doing this here:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector_import.php#L125

Basically, you need register a callback function to be called whenever the Web Connector authenticates:

```
$hooks = array(
    QuickBooks_WebConnector_Handlers::HOOK_LOGINSUCCESS => '_quickbooks_hook_loginsuccess',     // call this whenever a successful login occurs
    );
```

And do your queuing in that function instead:

```
function _quickbooks_hook_loginsuccess($requestID, $user, $hook, &$err, $hook_data, $callback_config)
{
    // For new users, we need to set up a few things
    // Fetch the queue instance
    $Queue = QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue_Singleton::getInstance();

    $Queue->enqueue(... whatever you want to do here ...)
}
```